# About the "index",i think it is right, when it is wrong. i do not know why

Tags: javascript, jquery

Look at the code:

```
<div class="test">
  <p><a href="#">1</a><a href="#">2</a><a href="#">3</a></p>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(".test a").each(function(index,element){
    $(element).click(function(){
        $(element).toggleClass("hover");                    // here works well
        $(".test div:eq(index)").slideToggle();             // here words wrong!
        });
});
</script>
```

above code, i think it should work well,but i am wrong. i do not know why. 
the second event:the "div" only slidetoggle the first, other div do not slidetoggle, whenever you click which "a" tag.

another way is wrong the same:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(".test a").click(function(){
    x = $(this).index();
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");                   // here works well
    $(".test div:eq(x)").slideToggle();             // here words wrong!
    });
</script>
```

by the way, i test `.get(index)` method too, the browser says: it does not support the method!

is there a master to solve this difficulty?

guys! Through testing again and again, i finally figured out. Let me show the correct code:

plan A:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(".test a").each(function(index,element){
    $(element).click(function(){
        $(element).toggleClass("hover");
        $(".test div").eq(index).slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

plan B:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(".test a").click(function(){
    x = $(this).index();
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    $(".test div").eq(x).slideToggle();
    });
</script>
```

OR Just:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(".test a").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    $(".test div").eq($(this).index()).slideToggle();
    });
</script>
```

plan C: come from @Šime Vidas `s method

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(".test").on("click","a",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    $(this).parent().siblings().eq($(this).index()).slideToggle();
    });
</script>
```

I test `:eq(" + index + ")` it does not work. but `.eq(index)` works well!
is that mean in selector `:eq(n)`,n could not be variable, but, in method `.eq(n)`, n can be variable?

I test `.on` method, it does not work with jquery-1.6.4.min, but works well with jquery-1.7.1.min.

There is another interesting thing:Plan B, the first code, the `x` variable is always be `0` in some more complicated condition, but the sencond code has no this problem. i can not figure this out yet.

thank you all guys, for all your methods and help, without you, i could not figure this out.

Comment: Try `$(".test div:eq("+index+")")` and `$(".test div:eq("+x+")")`.

Comment: Your HTML structure is flawed. You should have two lists (UL elements) - one for the links and one for the content (the stuff in the DIV's)...

Comment: I also think you should actually link those links to the different sections. Just give them unique IDs and link like so: `<a href="#section-1">1</a>`. Then you could also use the href value to slideToggle the correct element + it works for people without JS as well!

Comment: selector `:eq(" + x + ")` could not work, but method `.eq(x)` work well. i do not know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( '.test' ).on( 'click', 'a', function () {
    $( this ).toggleClass( 'hover' );
    $( this ).parent().siblings().eq( $( this ).index() ).slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to break your string and insert the *actual* value for `index` into your selector.

Change

```
$(".test div:eq(index)").slideToggle();  // here works incorrectly!
});
```

To

```
$(".test div:eq(" + index + ")").slideToggle();   // should work now!
});
```

---

And the same thing for your second error.

Change

```
$(".test div:eq(x)").slideToggle();
```

to

```
$(".test div:eq(" + x + ")").slideToggle();
```

Comment: selector `:eq(" + x + ")` could not work, but method `.eq(x)` work well. i do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(".test a").each(function(index,element){
    $(element).click(function(){
        $(element).toggleClass("hover");                    // here works well
        $(".test div:eq(" + index + ")").slideToggle();             // here words wrong!
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmm... maybe something like this using a closure and changing the index to the value not the string name.

```
$(".test a").each(function(index,element){
    var closureIndex=index;
    var closureElement=element;

    $(element).click(function(){
        $(closureElement).toggleClass("hover");                  
        $(".test div:eq("+closureIndex+")").slideToggle();      
        });
});
```